# Why variable does not change after changing it within a for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int j = 1;
    for (int i=0, j=1; i<10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << j << std::endl;
        j++;
    }
    std::cout << j << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is my output:

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
1
```

I just want to know why the value of j does not change out

Comment: The for loop has its own local `j`. Consider what `int i = 0, j = 1` does.

Comment: You have two variables names j.  One declared outside loop and one declared in the for statement.

Comment: `int i=0, j=1` means `int i=0; int j=1;`, not `int i=0; j=1;`.

Comment: after a bit of pushing (`-Werror -Wshadow`), gcc can report the mistake in your code as an error: https://godbolt.org/z/GT95GovEs,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two variables `j`:

```
    int j = 1; // 1st "j" here
    for (int i=0, j=1; i<10; i++) // 2nd "j" here
```

You are modifying 2nd `j` in the loop and printing 1st `j` after the loop.

Comment: It's quite possible OP did not intend to create a second var. In this case, they could use (the not so nice) `for (int i=(j=1,0); i<10; i++)`

Comment: @Jeffrey I think it should simply be `for (int i=0; i<10; i++)` in this case because `j` is already initialized to `1` at the declaration.

Comment: yeah. The mystery really is why specify `j=1` at that exact location